# Horizontal scroll using keyframes in Firefox

Tags: html, css

I am working on a CSS-only carousel with an autoplay feature.

A `keyframe` animation sets a `margin-left` to `.slide-snapper` (`div` which controls `scroll-snap-align` and the animations) which causes the slide to move to the left. It works totally fine in Chrome, but in Firefox setting a `margin-left` (or `left` alternatively) has no effect on the scroll. If inspected you can see the `div` element moving but without the expected effect.

Why is this behavior different in Firefox?

```css
*, *:after, *:before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* Example images */
#slide_1 {
    background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579353977828-2a4eab540b9a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8c2FtcGxlfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60);
}
#slide_2 {
    background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1561336313-0bd5e0b27ec8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8c2FtcGxlfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60);
}
#slide_3 {
    background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1600716051809-e997e11a5d52?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8c2FtcGxlfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60);
}
#slide_4 {
    background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1524419986249-348e8fa6ad4a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTB8fHNhbXBsZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60);
}
.li_slide {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
/* Animations */
@keyframes tonext {
    75% {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    95% {
        margin-left: calc(100% + 150px);
    }
    98% {
        margin-left: calc(100% + 150px);
    }
    99% {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
@keyframes snap {
    96% {
        scroll-snap-align: start;
    }
    97% {
        scroll-snap-align: none;
    }
    99% {
        scroll-snap-align: none;
    }
    100% {
        scroll-snap-align: start;
    }
}
@keyframes tostart {
    75% {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    95% {
        margin-left: calc(-300% - 450px);
    }
    98% {
        margin-left: calc(-300% - 450px);
    }
    99% {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
/* Reset */
ol, li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#pSlider {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /* Left, Right Navigation Arrows */
}
#pSlider #slider-container {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
#pSlider #slider-container .li_slide {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: khaki;
    flex: none;
    margin-right: 150px;
}
#pSlider #slider-container .li_slide:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: mediumaquamarine;
}
#pSlider #slider-container .li_slide:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
#pSlider #slider-container .li_slide .slide-snapper {
    /* Auto play */
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    animation: tonext 4s infinite ease, snap 4s infinite ease;
}
@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
    #pSlider #slider-container .li_slide .slide-snapper {
        animation-name: none;
    }
}
#pSlider #slider-container .li_slide:last-child .slide-snapper {
    animation-name: tostart, snap;
}
#pSlider #slider-container:hover .li_slide .slide-snapper, #pSlider #slider-container:focus-within .li_slide .slide-snapper {
    animation-name: none;
}
#pSlider:before, #pSlider:after, #pSlider .prev_slide, #pSlider .next_slide {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 30px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#pSlider:before, #pSlider:after {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 70%;
}
#pSlider .next_slide {
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
}
#pSlider .prev_slide {
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
}
#pSlider:before, #pSlider .prev_slide {
    content: "";
    left: 0px;
}
#pSlider:after, #pSlider .next_slide {
    content: "";
    right: 0px;
}
#pSlider:after {
    z-index: 1;
    /* set underneath .next_slide (z: 2)*/
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='40' height='60' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1'%3E%3Cpolyline points='10 10 30 30 10 50' stroke='rgba(255,255,255,0.9)' stroke-width='4' stroke-linecap='butt' fill='none' stroke-linejoin='round'%3E&lt;%3C/polyline%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
#pSlider:before {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='40' height='60' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1'%3E%3Cpolyline points='30 10 10 30 30 50' stroke='rgba(255,255,255,0.9)' stroke-width='4' stroke-linecap='butt' fill='none' stroke-linejoin='round'%3E&gt;%3C/polyline%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
/* Scrollbar */
#pSlider #slider-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
    height: 5px;
}
#pSlider #slider-container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
#pSlider #slider-container::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: transparent;
}

/* Input */

#sliderSettings {
  text-align: center;
}

#slider-width, #slider-height {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px; 
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h2>CSS Autoplay Carousel</h2>
<div id="sliderSettings">
  <label for="slider-width">Slider width in px:</label>
  <input type="text" id="slider-width" name="slider-width" minlength="2" maxlength="4" size="6" placeholder="300">
  <label for="slider-height">Slider height in px:</label>
  <input type="text" id="slider-height" name="slider-height" minlength="2" maxlength="4" size="6" placeholder="300">
</div>

<div id="pSlider">
  <ol id="slider-container" dir="ltr">
    <li id="slide_1" class="li_slide">
      <div class="slide-snapper"></div>
      <a class="prev_slide" href="#slide_4"></a> <a class="next_slide" href="#slide_2"></a> </li>
    <li id="slide_2" class="li_slide">
      <div class="slide-snapper"></div>
      <a class="prev_slide" href="#slide_1"></a> <a class="next_slide" href="#slide_3"></a> </li>
    <li id="slide_3" class="li_slide">
      <div class="slide-snapper"></div>
      <a class="prev_slide" href="#slide_2"></a> <a class="next_slide" href="#slide_4"></a> </li>
    <li id="slide_4" class="li_slide">
      <div  class="slide-snapper"></div>
      <a class="prev_slide" href="#slide_3"></a> <a class="next_slide" href="#slide_1"></a> </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Simplified version:

```css
@keyframes tonext {
    75% {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    95% {
        margin-left: calc(100% + 150px);
    }
    98% {
        margin-left: calc(100% + 150px);
    }
    99% {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes snap {
    96% {
        scroll-snap-align: start;
    }
    97% {
        scroll-snap-align: none;
    }
    99% {
        scroll-snap-align: none;
    }
    100% {
        scroll-snap-align: start;
    }
}

#pSlider {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /* Left, Right Navigation Arrows */
}
#pSlider #slider-container {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
#pSlider #slider-container .li_slide {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: khaki;
    flex: none;
    margin-right: 150px;
}
#pSlider #slider-container .li_slide:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: mediumaquamarine;
}
#pSlider #slider-container .li_slide:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
#pSlider #slider-container .li_slide .slide-snapper {
    /* Auto play */
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    animation: tonext 4s infinite ease, snap 4s infinite ease;
}

#pSlider #slider-container .li_slide:last-child .slide-snapper {
  animation: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="pSlider">
  <div id="slider-container">
    <div id="slide_1" class="li_slide">
      <div class="slide-snapper"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="slide_2" class="li_slide">
      <div class="slide-snapper"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing I noticed, unless you interact with the container Firefox doesn't snap the scroll bar. Couldn't find anything related on the [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=css).
If you run following snippet in Firefox. The scroll will snap after you click anywhere on the container.

```js
if ("scrollRestoration" in history) {
  history.scrollRestoration = "manual";
}
```

```css
#pSlider {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* Left, Right Navigation Arrows */
}

#pSlider #slider-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#pSlider #slider-container .li_slide {
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  abackground-color: khaki;
  flex: none;
  margin-right: 150px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#pSlider #slider-container .li_slide .slide-snapper {
  /* Auto play */
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: calc(100% + 150px);
  border: 1px dashed red;
  background-color: rgb(246, 209, 130);
}
```

```html
<div id="pSlider">
  <div id="slider-container">
    <div id="slide_1" class="li_slide">
      Slide
      <div class="slide-snapper">Snapper</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
Open in Firefox and click anywhere on the container.
```

---

I created a basic CSS only carousel without scroll snapping a while ago:

```css
:root {
  /* no of slides excluding last duplicate */
  --slide-count: 4;
  /* time that a slide stays idle and slides left */
  /* 70% idle, 30% sliding animation */
  --slide-time: 3s;
  --carousel-width: 300px;
  --carousel-height: 150px;
}

body {
  height: 95vh;
  width: 95vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.carousel {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: var(--carousel-width);
  height: var(--carousel-height);
  white-space: nowrap;
  contain: layout style;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  counter-reset: count;
}

.slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  flex: none;
  animation-name: shiftMe, slideMe;
  animation-duration: calc(var(--slide-time) * var(--slide-count)), var(--slide-time);
  animation-timing-function: steps(var(--slide-count), end), ease-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  counter-increment: count;
  position: relative;
}

.slide::before {
  content: counter(count);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.slide:last-child::before {
  content: "1";
}

@keyframes shiftMe {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    left: calc(var(--carousel-width) * var(--slide-count) * -1);
  }
}

@keyframes slideMe {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  70% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(calc(var(--carousel-width) * -1));
  }
}

.carousel:hover .slide {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.slide:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: rgba(173, 216, 230, 0.7);
}

.slide:nth-child(odd),
.slide:last-child {
  background-color: rgba(144, 238, 144, 0.7);
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <div class=slide><img src="https://developer.mozilla.org/static/media/chrome.4c570865.svg"></div>
  <div class=slide><img src="https://developer.mozilla.org/static/media/safari.3679eb31.svg"></div>
  <div class=slide><img src="https://developer.mozilla.org/static/media/firefox.51d8a59c.svg"></div>
  <div class=slide><img src="https://developer.mozilla.org/static/media/edge.40018f6a.svg"></div>
  <div class=slide><img src="https://developer.mozilla.org/static/media/chrome.4c570865.svg"></div>
```

It is a stateful carousel so you can't jump slides. You have to duplicate first slide and put it at the end to make it seamless.

[Vertical version](https://codepen.io/onkarruikar/full/RwZzrMp)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 
Not only does it not snap but if you play with the `margin-left` (or `left`) of the snapper div you can actually see it causing a scroll in other browsers except for Firefox. I think the problem might lie in that behavior but I can't find anything on it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you'd prefer a **CSS-only** solution.

But a mere 7 lines of javascript will ensure this slideshow's **autoplay feature** works cross-browser (including in Firefox):

```
let currentSlideIndex = 1;
const numberOfSlides = document.querySelectorAll('.li_slide').length;

const moveToNextSlide = () => {
  let currentSlide = document.querySelector('#slide_' + currentSlideIndex);
  currentSlide.querySelector('.next_slide').click();
  currentSlideIndex = (currentSlideIndex === numberOfSlides) ? 1 : currentSlideIndex + 1;
}

const autoRunSlideshow = setInterval(moveToNextSlide, 4000);
```

---

**Working Example:**

```js
let currentSlideIndex = 1;
const numberOfSlides = document.querySelectorAll('.li_slide').length;

const moveToNextSlide = () => {
 
  let currentSlide = document.querySelector('#slide_' + currentSlideIndex);
  currentSlide.querySelector('.next_slide').click();
  currentSlideIndex = (currentSlideIndex === numberOfSlides) ? 1 : currentSlideIndex + 1;
}

const autoRunSlideshow = setInterval(moveToNextSlide, 4000);
```

```css
*, *:after, *:before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* Example images */
#slide_1 {
    background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579353977828-2a4eab540b9a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8c2FtcGxlfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60);
}
#slide_2 {
    background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1561336313-0bd5e0b27ec8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8c2FtcGxlfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60);
}
#slide_3 {
    background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1600716051809-e997e11a5d52?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8c2FtcGxlfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60);
}
#slide_4 {
    background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1524419986249-348e8fa6ad4a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTB8fHNhbXBsZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60);
}
.li_slide {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
/* Animations */
@keyframes tonext {
    75% {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    95% {
        margin-left: calc(100% + 150px);
    }
    98% {
        margin-left: calc(100% + 150px);
    }
    99% {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
@keyframes snap {
    96% {
        scroll-snap-align: start;
    }
    97% {
        scroll-snap-align: none;
    }
    99% {
        scroll-snap-align: none;
    }
    100% {
        scroll-snap-align: start;
    }
}
@keyframes tostart {
    75% {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    95% {
        margin-left: calc(-300% - 450px);
    }
    98% {
        margin-left: calc(-300% - 450px);
    }
    99% {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
/* Reset */
ol, li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#pSlider {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /* Left, Right Navigation Arrows */
}
#pSlider #slider-container {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
#pSlider #slider-container .li_slide {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: khaki;
    flex: none;
    margin-right: 150px;
}
#pSlider #slider-container .li_slide:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: mediumaquamarine;
}
#pSlider #slider-container .li_slide:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
#pSlider #slider-container .li_slide .slide-snapper {
    /* Auto play */
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    animation: tonext 4s infinite ease, snap 4s infinite ease;
}
@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
    #pSlider #slider-container .li_slide .slide-snapper {
        animation-name: none;
    }
}
#pSlider #slider-container .li_slide:last-child .slide-snapper {
    animation-name: tostart, snap;
}
#pSlider #slider-container:hover .li_slide .slide-snapper, #pSlider #slider-container:focus-within .li_slide .slide-snapper {
    animation-name: none;
}
#pSlider:before, #pSlider:after, #pSlider .prev_slide, #pSlider .next_slide {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 30px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#pSlider:before, #pSlider:after {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 70%;
}
#pSlider .next_slide {
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
}
#pSlider .prev_slide {
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
}
#pSlider:before, #pSlider .prev_slide {
    content: "";
    left: 0px;
}
#pSlider:after, #pSlider .next_slide {
    content: "";
    right: 0px;
}
#pSlider:after {
    z-index: 1;
    /* set underneath .next_slide (z: 2)*/
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='40' height='60' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1'%3E%3Cpolyline points='10 10 30 30 10 50' stroke='rgba(255,255,255,0.9)' stroke-width='4' stroke-linecap='butt' fill='none' stroke-linejoin='round'%3E&lt;%3C/polyline%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
#pSlider:before {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='40' height='60' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1'%3E%3Cpolyline points='30 10 10 30 30 50' stroke='rgba(255,255,255,0.9)' stroke-width='4' stroke-linecap='butt' fill='none' stroke-linejoin='round'%3E&gt;%3C/polyline%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
/* Scrollbar */
#pSlider #slider-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
    height: 5px;
}
#pSlider #slider-container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
#pSlider #slider-container::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: transparent;
}

/* Input */

#sliderSettings {
  text-align: center;
}

#slider-width, #slider-height {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px; 
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h2>CSS Autoplay Carousel</h2>
<div id="sliderSettings">
  <label for="slider-width">Slider width in px:</label>
  <input type="text" id="slider-width" name="slider-width" minlength="2" maxlength="4" size="6" placeholder="300">
  <label for="slider-height">Slider height in px:</label>
  <input type="text" id="slider-height" name="slider-height" minlength="2" maxlength="4" size="6" placeholder="300">
</div>

<div id="pSlider">
  <ol id="slider-container" dir="ltr">
    <li id="slide_1" class="li_slide">
      <div class="slide-snapper"></div>
      <a class="prev_slide" href="#slide_4"></a> <a class="next_slide" href="#slide_2"></a> </li>
    <li id="slide_2" class="li_slide">
      <div class="slide-snapper"></div>
      <a class="prev_slide" href="#slide_1"></a> <a class="next_slide" href="#slide_3"></a> </li>
    <li id="slide_3" class="li_slide">
      <div class="slide-snapper"></div>
      <a class="prev_slide" href="#slide_2"></a> <a class="next_slide" href="#slide_4"></a> </li>
    <li id="slide_4" class="li_slide">
      <div  class="slide-snapper"></div>
      <a class="prev_slide" href="#slide_3"></a> <a class="next_slide" href="#slide_1"></a> </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Appreciate the JavaScript solution. Indeed was looking for a CSS only solution and especially for an explanation why it does not work even if there is no solution.
Thank you.