# Automatic Scroll

Tags: html, css

When creating a horizontal scroll with `scroll-snap-type` and `scroll-snap-align` you can scroll the carousel by setting a keyframes animation with `transform: translateX()`, `margin-left` or `left`. When you remove one or both of these properties this behaviour is lost. What is happening here and why is it behaving differently on　Firefox?

```css
#slide_1 {
    background-color: darkblue;
}
#slide_2 {
    background-color: orange;
}

/* Animations */
@keyframes tonext {
    0% {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    100% {
        margin-left: calc(100% + 150px);
    }
}

ol, li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#pSlider {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#pSlider #slider-container {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
#pSlider #slider-container .li_slide {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    flex: none;
    margin-right: 150px;
}
#pSlider #slider-container .li_slide:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
#pSlider #slider-container .li_slide .slide-snapper {
    /* Auto play */
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    animation: tonext 4s infinite ease alternate;
}
```

```html
<div id="pSlider">
  <ol id="slider-container" dir="ltr">
    <li id="slide_1" class="li_slide">
      <div class="slide-snapper"></div>
    </li>
    <li id="slide_2" class="li_slide">
      <div class="slide-snapper"></div>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/pscldhw/pen/eYejYxW

Comment: Where have you used `transform: translateX()` as you say?

Comment: IMHO that's a pretty awful way to animate a carousel. Because you're putting it into a flexbox, one can interrupts it horizontally with the mouse/trackpad and it gets a jittery effect.

Comment: @NicolasGoosen You could use `transform: translateX()` (or `left`) in place of `margin-left` in the keyframes too is what I was trying to say. --- This is just a simplified version of my actual carousel where hovering over it stops the animation so that is not really a problem. But even if this would be a bad approach I still badly want to know why Firefox behaves differently.

Comment: Because you're using an animation, what's the point of the scroll snaps? Maybe those are what's interfering with Firefox?

Comment: @NicolasGoosen To allow (user-friendly) manual navigation too. https://codepen.io/pscldhw/pen/qBVVZVg This is the actual carousel. It works perfectly in Chrome and Edge.

Comment: Sorry, I see what you mean now. It wasn't obvious from your original snippet what you were trying to do, but yes, seeing the finished carousel now we need to find the minimum example of where exactly Firefox breaks.

Comment: @NicolasGoosen Np my explanation was bad. What you can see when you inspect the snapper element with Firefox is, that it is moving accordingly to the keyframes animation but is not causing any scroll. I have a feeling it has something to do with scrolling being ever so slightly differently implemented in firefox in general but that's just a guess.  I posted a very similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71136729/horizontal-scroll-using-keyframes-in-firefox where someone answered that you need interaction in firefox but that's still no explanation really